# Joomla Custom Html Module How too link img code

Tags: html, joomla

I have the following as the html code to display a circular image with animation, how do I link the actual image file, have tried the a-href function but not linking, codes used is as below:

```
[feature bgcolor="#5cc2e5" textcolor="white" border="false" img="images/feature/01.jpg"]
```

Example can be seen at: http://www.envande.com/index.php

Thanks.

Comment: Try @ this link.
http://ran.ge/2009/11/11/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/

Answer (score 0):

You can make the entire div clickable using this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(".feature-rounded").click(function() {
  window.location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); // use link from readmore button
  return false;
});
```

As an alternative, have you tried wrapping your code inside an `<a href...` tag? (I assume you're using a plugin to generate the HTML output seen on your website) :

```
<a href="yourlink.html">[feature bgcolor="#5cc2e5" textcolor="white" border="false" img="images/feature/01.jpg"]</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Johan, second <a href> option worked a charm :)

Comment: Great. I thought you already tried that when you said you had `tried the a-href function`. :)